# proxying through corporate firewall

Tags: proxy, firewall, mod-proxy, tunnel

I'm trying to get some protocols work through my company's firewall. Until now I have been succesfull in masking either http or https data by setting a http proxy on localhost and one on a remote server I own. The communication is done via $_POSTed and received modified .bmp files that contain a header and the encripted serialised request array. 
This works fine, but there are a few drawbacks that make me think I might have taken a wrong approach.
Firstly I do not use apache's mod-proxy. instead I just created a local subdomain (proxy.localhost) and use that in browser's proxy settings. the subdomain's index.php does all the work. This creates some problems. I cannot use http and https simultaneously or the server will complain of using either "http on a https enabled port" or "incoresc ssl response length".

The second problem is, well, other protocols. I could make use of some ftp, sftp, remote deskoptop, ssh, nust name another... I need it

there are 2 solutions I can think of: First is if I run a php script in CLI so that it listens on a predefined port and handles the requests differently, or some sort of ssh tunnel. Problem is I haven't had any success with freeSSHd and putty because of my ignorance.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I used the free version of bitvise SSH Client and server and it seems to work just fine.